# What is a "pony soldier"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

In New Hampshire yesterday, presidential candidate Biden [called a voter a "lying, dog-faced pony soldier"](https://news.grabien.com/story-biden-calls-skeptical-new-hampshire-voter-lying-dog-faced-po).

In this context, what is meant by a "pony soldier"?

Comment: In the context, it seems to be an **insult**, which doesn't have to mean anything, just sound bad. The [*Daily Caller*](https://dailycaller.com/2020/02/09/biden-woman-lying-dog-faced-pony-soldier-new-hampshire/) says “So, apparently Biden has used this ‘dog-faced pony soldier’ phrase before, but about Republicans. It’s allegedly from a film where an Indian chief tells John Wayne: ‘This is a lying dog-faced pony soldier,'” Weinberger tweeted, adding a query for verification. “However, haven’t been able to verify that line. Any John Wayne experts?”

Comment: Isn't he demeaning the voter by implying pathetic weakness? Like "I curse you and the poodle you rode in on" rather than at least "the horse you rode in on"?

Comment: He may have meant to say "ponyboy":  https://www.dictionary.com/e/fictional-characters/ponyboy/

Comment: He's attempting to use the quote in the same manner someone would jokingly say, "You're pulling my leg." Of course, in true Biden fashion, he chooses the worst time to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Biden was mixing his metaphors. There are several movies in question, the 1949 John Wayne film “She Wore a Yellow Ribbon," the phrase “dog-faced soldiers” occurs. While the term “pony soldiers” occurs in the 1953 John Wayne movie “Hondo” and the 1952 Tyrone Power western “Pony Soldier.” This basically backs up Russ Tinder's answer. In the Power movie, a Pony Soldier is a Royal Canadian Mountie. Essentially, it appears to be a homespun way to jokingly call someone a liar concocted by Biden from memories of the movies mentioned above.

Comment: This article from Slate shows the film clips from which this phrase apparently germinated. https://slate.com/culture/2020/02/joe-biden-dog-faced-pony-soldier-john-wayne-tyrone-power.html

Comment: What was the context and meaning of "dog-faced" there?

Answer (score 3):

Dog faced pony soldier is referencing an Indian scout (dog faced) pony soldier (U.S. Cavalry). It is not just any Cavalry recruit, but instead an Indian helping the Cavalry.

Comment: As in someone who appears to be in the wrong camp.

Comment: Do you have any citation for 'dog faced' meaning 'indian scout'

Comment: Am I reading this right that this is a racial epithet?

Comment: I have my doubts:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogface_(military)

Comment: I found a https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/3c469cd9-77ea-48af-adca-9bbe4c712a77/617073.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The voter in question was a young women with short cropped hair. The "idiom" was insulting and suggestive on several levels. It is not idiomatic if the phrase was never in common usage by any group at any time period. It is more likely a "senior moment".

Comment: Political biases irrelevant, Biden is having a lot of senior moments, and is frequently antagonistic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common idiom.  There is an old movie called "Pony Soldier", based on the Royal Canadian Mounted Police, but it's not clear how that reference would relate, unless Biden was hinting that the guy was Canadian.

Comment: This page: [The Last of the Pony Soldiers](https://www.chuckhawks.com/last_pony_soldier.htm) claims "the term Pony Soldier was bestowed on members of the US Cavalry, who rode and fought in the Plains Indian wars of post Civil War history."

Comment: I doubt that this was the meaning intended.